# SQL Server Category List SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to show categories in one line, let's give an example like this:

Category for a product iPhone 6 -> Apple -> Mobile Phones -> Electronics

I just want to show the current category of the product + a top category + the top category, so:

Electronic / ... / Apple / iPhone 6, I want to show the ...  between categories that I don't want to show.

Here is my code

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a1.*
    FROM dbo.viewFeatureProductCategory a1
    WHERE a1.Id = 1000184
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a2.*
    FROM dbo.viewFeatureProductCategory a2
    join cte c on a2.Id = c.ParentId
) SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING((SELECT ' / ' + SPACE (1) + Name as 'data()' FROM cte order by ParentId for XML PATH('')), 4, 99999) from cte
```

and here is result of the code

[image]

Comment: it's better to post a sample of input table and the expected output.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Providing DDL and sample data as text helps us help you. Images, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of the previous `Name` value, as well as the starting `Name` value. Then filter the CTE to the top level row and concatenate the values together.

`CONCAT_WS` concatenates values with a separator.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a1.ParentId, a1.Name, PreviousName = NULL, OriginalName = a1.Name
    FROM dbo.viewFeatureProductCategory a1
    WHERE a1.Id = 1000184

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a2.ParentId, a2.Name, PreviousName = c.Name, OriginalName = c.OriginalName 
    FROM dbo.viewFeatureProductCategory a2
    JOIN cte c on a2.Id = c.ParentId
)
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' / ', cte.Name, '...', cte.PreviousName, cte.OriginalName)
FROM cte
WHERE cte.ParentId IS NULL;
```

Alternatively, if you only want the *bottom* two levels, you can do this

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a1.ParentId, a1.Name, Name2 = NULL, OriginalName = a1.Name
    FROM dbo.viewFeatureProductCategory a1
    WHERE a1.Id = 1000184

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a2.ParentId, a2.Name, ISNULL(c.Name2, c.Name), c.OriginalName 
    FROM dbo.viewFeatureProductCategory a2
    JOIN cte c on a2.Id = c.ParentId
)
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' / ', cte.OriginalName, cte.Name2, '...', cte.Name)
FROM cte
WHERE cte.ParentId IS NULL;
```